# Help calculating this determinant using induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I want to show that the determinant of the $(n \times n)$ matrix $$J(\alpha)=\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & \frac{1}{2\alpha} & \\
\frac{\alpha}{2} & -\lambda & \\
 &&\ddots&\frac{1}{2\alpha}\\
 &&\frac{\alpha}{2} &-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}$$ is independent of $\alpha$.

With the Laplace expansion I got $D_n=-\lambda D_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4}D_{n-2}$ (where $D_n$ is the determinant for $n$). Problem: I need a formula to prove this with induction, for $1\leq n \leq 5$ it holds: $D_n=(-1)^{n}\lambda^n+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{4}\lambda^{n-2}+(-1)^n\frac{n-2}{4^2}\lambda^{n-4}$ but another $\lambda$ term appears for every second $n$. I struggle to write the determinant formula as a sum $\sum_{j=1}^n$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you established a recurrence relation that’s (1) independent of $\alpha$ and (2) that applied for $n\ge 3$, it suffices to check that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are independent of $\alpha$.

Comment: but the task says "show by induction" :(